# Is there any app to help track my expenses and make a pie graph each month?

Tags: software-recommendation, finance

Is there an Ubuntu app to help track my expenses and make a pie graph each month?

I want to write down all my receipts and payments and personal purchases and save them on my PC to generate a family finance thing to show my wife every month.

Does anyone do something similar and have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

[Gnucash](http://www.gnucash.org/) is one option. It's available in the repositories.

Comment: Can it export the whole database to a spreadsheet (just in case I need to export the data 15 years later from now?)

Comment: Simply follow the provided link to find out :) As data can be stored in XML format, there you have one "export" ready. You can also store to a database (which also is easily exported, e.g. using a dump or even make your own stuff with SQL). And if you look into the FAQ, it even has a separate section on [Importing and Exporting data](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Importing.2FExporting_Data).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, depending on your desktop environment and requirements, a lot of other solutions are available, as e.g. [KMyMoney](http://kmymoney2.sourceforge.net/) for KDE and more. Wikipedia has a specific category on [Linux accounting software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aLinux_accounting_software), and there's also a [Comparison of accounting software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_accounting_software) you might want to check.